# How can I combine 4 bytes into a 32 bit unsigned integer?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to convert 4 bytes into a 32 bit unsigned integer.

I thought maybe something like:

```
UInt32 combined = (UInt32)((map[i] << 32) | (map[i+1] << 24) | (map[i+2] << 16) | (map[i+3] << 8));
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 13):

Your shifts are all off by 8. Shift by 24, 16, 8, and 0.

Comment: Assuming you choose to stick with the math rather than delegate, yes.

Comment: @Ignacio, the confusing part for me is that I'm shifting a byte more positions than it has.  So, why does shifting a byte 24 positions work?  It isn't cast to the 32bit int until after all the shifts.

Comment: The byte's value occupies bits 1 through 8. You want to shift it 24 bits so it occupies bits 24 through 32. If you shift if 32 bits, it goes off the end into oblivion.

Comment: The compiler is aware of that. But it's still performing the operation in 32 bits, regardless of the size of the left operand.

Comment: @Ignacio, can I read about this compiler behavior of using 32 bits for these operations even if the type being operated on is smaller than that?  I just want to make sense of it.

Comment: @Pocki: Everything is aligned on the zeroeth (rightmost, least significant bit).  Each byte takes up eight bits, so to get the most significant bit in the most significant byte to the leftmost (most significant) position in the 32 bit word, you have to shift it by 24 bits.  The least-significant byte doesn't have to be shifted at all.  Write a simple illustration of this on a piece of paper, so you can visualize it.

Comment: @Pocki: I don't have a reference for it myself, but I know that C compilers operate in this manner and I can see how the designers of C# would want that behavior to seem familiar to developers coming over.

Comment: @Rober Harvey, I understand that portion.  What I don't fully understand is how you can even shift a ~byte~ 24 bits.  A byte holds 8 bits, so shifting it 24 positions would be too much.  It isn't converted to the 32 bit uint until after the shifts.  So how is it able to perform the shifts which are larger than bytes?  Ignacio claims the shifts are being performed with 32 bits available.  How?

Comment: @Robert: What he doesn't get is that since `map[n]` is only 8 bits in size, why a shift larger than 8 doesn't clear it completely.

Comment: @Pocki: The shifting operators automatically work on `int`s at a minimum, so they put a `byte` or a `short` into an `int` and then do the shift. If the value is already a `long`, it doesn't decrease the size.

Comment: @Pocki: Joel is correct.  All bytes are cast to a 32 bit integer value *before the shifting is performed.*

Comment: Thanks everyone for explaining that!  That was the disconnect that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I just noticed that shifting a `ushort` also converts to `int` rather than `uint`. `long l = (uint)255 << 24` and `long l = 255 << 24` have very different results.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class.

Specifically, [this overload.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32.aspx)

Comment: and.. the reason you would use this over manual shifts is because if my C# code were to ever be compiled on an architecture with a different endianess than it would still work?

Comment: @Pocki: No, bit-shifting will always work the same way, no matter which order the actual bytes themselves are stored in memory. `<<` always shifts bits "higher", and `>>` shifts them "lower".

Comment: @Pocki: Yes, *the conversion is endian-specific.*  There is a system-specific flag that the class uses to adjust the conversion.  The relevant code looks like this: `if (IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return (((numRef[0] | (numRef[1] << 8)) | (numRef[2] << 0x10)) | (numRef[3] << 0x18));
        }
        return ((((numRef[0] << 0x18) | (numRef[1] << 0x10)) | (numRef[2] << 8)) | numRef[3]);`

Answer (score 7):

[BitConverter.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx)

You can always do something like this:

```
public static unsafe int ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)
{
    fixed (byte* numRef = &(value[startIndex]))
    {
        if ((startIndex % 4) == 0)
        {
            return *(((int*)numRef));
        }
        if (IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return (((numRef[0] | (numRef[1] << 8)) | (numRef[2] << 0x10)) | (numRef[3] << 0x18));
        }
        return ((((numRef[0] << 0x18) | (numRef[1] << 0x10)) | (numRef[2] << 8)) | numRef[3]);
    }
}
```

But this would be reinventing the wheel, as this is actually how `BitConverter.ToInt32()` is implemented.