# Convert two bytes to Int16 in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, byte, arrays, short

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Good way to convert between short and bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442583/good-way-to-convert-between-short-and-bytes)
>   [How can I combine 4 bytes into a 32 bit unsigned integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406324/how-can-i-combine-4-bytes-into-a-32-bit-unsigned-integer)

Alright , so I am developing this virtual machine and it has 64 kbs of memory. I am using a byte[] array for the memory and I have one problem. How would I convert 2 bytes to a short or 4 bytes to a Int32?

Comment: This should help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383265/convert-4-bytes-to-int

Comment: @Kurru, that's a Java question, this one is C#.  Definitely not a duplicate and the correct answer is very different, Java and .NET class libraries have different classes.

Comment: @Grunt what's the endianness of your virtual machine? Big, little or native?

Comment: @Julien: This is a dupe of many other questions, but the one you found is a particularly bad one.

Comment: @Ben: I have to agree, I chose a little too fast. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Samuel Neff: Ah forgot to check. Have seen so many questions like that, didnt even check the language

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Others suggested BitConverter.
Here is a different solution

Short:

```
var myShort = (short) (myByteArray[0] << 8 | myByteArray[1]);
```

Int32

```
var myint = myByteArray[0] << 24 | myByteArray[1] << 16 | myByteArray[2] << 8 | myByteArray[3];
```

Mind the endianness though.

Comment: This is the solution for big endian numbers. For little Endian you will need to pair up the shifts and indizes differently.

Comment: Why write code that is exactly the same as what the framework already provides for you?

Comment: @Sven the framework does not provide you with an architecture independent array to integer conversion.

Comment: @Sven: What CodeInChaos said and also that it is always good to learn how things are done. If you have a method, SolveAllMathProblems(), you will still not know math if you know how to use that method.

Comment: My vote here. Although this is not an elegant way to convert since it's not reliable across different platforms, I tested several way to do it time ago and it's the fastest. On some platforms it far exceed the equivalent C code.

Comment: Doing the conversion explicitly is the most reliable way **if** you are receiving the data from an external source, since the endianness has to be explicit.

Comment: +1 I do not think BitConverter is available on the .Net MicroFramework

Answer (score 8):

You can use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).  If it's a virtual machine, you'll want to double check the expected endian-ness (in case it's reversed from your PC's endian-ness.)

Answer (score 4):

```
// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Where bytes is your array of bytes that is to be converted.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

Comment: reversing the array representing the memory of the VM just to read a value is insane(and makes the function im`Pure`) . If you want to go that way you need to copy out the part of the array containing the number.

Comment: If you're doing that for all memory stored as a byte array, then I agree. But I would assume you'd only be doing that for the accessed portion of memory, so it wouldn't be so bad. The reason I included that if statement was to show that BitConverter has an IsLittleEndian property

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I believe `bytes` is supposed to represent the byte array to convert. Not the entire 64kB memory.

Comment: @Sani made that clarification in the answer as well :)